# Installing PGAdmin 3

Tags: linux, redhat, postgresql

How can I install pgAdmin3 on RHEL 4?

I've install it but I can't access it. After `./configure`, I don't know what I should do.

I want access to the postgresql with a GUI, because from i don't understand the command line.

Comment: I think you really do need to get someone in to help you.

Comment: Please [read this Meta topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) and improve your question. Right now you're essentially saying "It doesn't work! Please give me the exact commands to type in!", which doesn't meet the "professional" requirement of this site -- we expect you to put in some effort and provide a *detailed* description of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

after configure usually follows a

```
make
```

and then

```
make install
```

(the last must be done as root)